# height of the text view to be dynamic inside a scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a text view inside a scroll view, I want to let the height of text view be dynamic as its content, because I don't want to scroll the text view alone, In fact I want to scroll the text view with the scroll view together.
[image]

In fact, I confused with the right menu of the image above, about the constraints height equals, less than, bigger than,...

I don't want to let the height stable, I want it dynamic, in my code:

```
 CGRect frame = self.detailTextView.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.detailTextView.contentSize.height;
    self.detailTextView.frame = frame;
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll.contentSize.width,
                                    200 + self.detailTextView.frame.size.height);
    [self.detailTextView setFrame:frame];
```

which detailTextView is the name of text view, and scroll is the name of the scroll view.

But it doesn't work properly, what shall I do please help!

Note: Is there any relation between this issue and the checkbox of (use AutoLayout), because it is checked in my application

Comment: no body is here to answer me?

Answer (score 0):

CarinaM

```
Use following method for getting dynamic height of textfield as per text. 
 -(CGFloat) GetHeightFoText:(NSString *)aStrTxt  FoWidth:(int)aIntWidth ForFontSize: (int)aIntFntSize
 {
  CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(aIntWidth,9999);
  CGSize expectedLabelSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:aIntFntSize]
                            constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
  return expectedLabelSize.height;
 }
```

Comment: I need dynamic height of text view and not text field

Comment: you can use it with textfield,textview,webview(if it contains html text),lable.Any controls.Disable scrolls in textview and webview

Answer (score 0):

What the problem is? I have seen only one issue that you need to disable the scrolling of `youtTextView`.